# Inner Shadow to UIImageView Top and Bottom only (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cagradientlayer

> I want to add the inner shadow to my UIImageView as follows: (following is the expected shadow needs to be added on image view)

[image]

> The shadow frame applied at Top and Bottom only not at Leading and
>   Trailing.
>
> I have tried the code below but did not get the expected output.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView * mapCover = [UIView new];
    CGRect frameImage = self.bgImageView.frame;
    frameImage.origin.x = -50;
    frameImage.size.width = frameImage.size.width+50;
    mapCover.frame = frameImage;
    [self.view addSubview:mapCover];

    CAGradientLayer * vertical = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    vertical.frame = mapCover.bounds;
    vertical.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor,
                       (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0f].CGColor,
                       (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0f].CGColor,
                       (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, nil];
    vertical.locations = @[@0.01,@0.1,@0.9,@0.99];
    [mapCover.layer insertSublayer:vertical atIndex:0];

    CAGradientLayer * horizontal = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    horizontal.frame = mapCover.bounds;
    horizontal.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                         (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0f].CGColor,
                         (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, nil];
    horizontal.locations = @[@0.01,@0.1,@0.9,@0.99];
    horizontal.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
    horizontal.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
    [self.bgImageView.layer insertSublayer:horizontal atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Your post does not make your question clear. Is the image what you are *trying* to get? Or is it the result of what you are currently doing? If it's your current result, you need to also show an image of what you *want* to get.

Comment: Sure I will update it

Answer (score 0):

> **Resolved!!!**
>
> Used the UIView category from below link: which has enum
>   Top|Bottom|Left|Right

```
// Add a shadow to the top and bottom of the view
[exampleView addInnerShadowWithRadius:3.0f
                             andColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.45f]
                          inDirection:NLInnerShadowDirectionBottom | NLInnerShadowDirectionTop];
```

http://www.nathanlampi.com/posts/10002/UIView-Inner-Shadow.html

[image]